# What did Mikael discover about the parade photos?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-girl-with-the-dragon-tattoo

In the 2011 American version of *The Girl with the Dragon Tattoo*, when Mikael is first looking on his computer through all the different parade photos; he notices something that seems important... you can tell based on the way the scene is shot and the look on his face.

Later, when Lisbeth is looking through his notes, she confirms this by saying something long the lines of "that was clever what you found with the parade photos".

What was it that he discovered?

Comment: Curious about the downvote?

Comment: Not me who DV’d but I remember it being clearly explained in the film.

Comment: @Darren It's definitely possible I missed it; but I found the plot as it related to the specifics of the murder and the clues being found very difficult to follow throughout. This wasn't the only question I had about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He sees Harriet reacting to something. She is looking past the photographer, so we cannot see who or what she sees, but her reaction is such that her expression goes from happy to fear when looking from one photo to the next.

Blomkvist then sees another photographer in the crowd next to Harriet, taking a photo in the same direction that Harriet is looking. He realises that this photographer will have captured whatever or whoever Harriet was reacting to.